# How to save the value of selected radio, so that when I am submitting the form I can send all the selected responses

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-native

I am developing a form in react native which is having radio buttons and text input and I want to save all the responses when I submit the form but I'm not able to understand how I can create an array that contain all the selected responses so that I can send to the backend.(Note using styled-components for styles)

The code looks like this

Feedback.tsx

```
const FeedBack = () => {
  const submitIcon = <Icon name="poll" size={24} color="#ffffff" />;
  return (
    <FeedBackMainContainer>
      <MainTextContainer>
        <MainText>we care about your valuable feedback ..!!</MainText> 
      </MainTextContainer>
      <CustomTextInput /> 
      <CustomCheckBox
        title={"do you love gardening ?"}
        options={["yes", "no"]}
      />
      <CustomCheckBox
        title={"how many plants do you have ?"}
        options={["0-10", "10-20", "more than 20"]}
      />
      <CustomButton
        title={"Submit"}
        icon={submitIcon}
        submit={true}
        toPage={"Submit"}
      />
    </FeedBackMainContainer>
  );
};
```

CustomCheckBox.tsx (using react-native-paper Radio button Group https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/radio-button-group.html)

```
const CustomCheckBox = ({ title, options }: Props) => {
  const [value, setVal] = useState(options[0]);
  console.log(value)
  return (
    <CheckBoxMainContainer>
      <RadioQuestionTitle>{title}</RadioQuestionTitle>
      <RadioButton.Group
        onValueChange={(val) => setVal(val)}
        value={value}
      >
        {options.map((item,index) => {
          return (
            <RadioOptinsContainer key={index}>
              <RadioButton color="#1f4623" value={item} />
              <TextStyle>{item}</TextStyle>
            </RadioOptinsContainer>
          );
        })}
      </RadioButton.Group>
    </CheckBoxMainContainer>
  );
};
```

I am getting the selected response in **value** but how do I save it uniquely?

[image: the form look like this]

Answer (score 0):

Couple of ways to do this. If your options are limited to a few, you could return the values in an object using callback function to the parent component.

Or you can wrap all the input and radio buttons in a form.

```
<form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}> 
  // form elements with name
</form>
```

You can access the value like this:
`event.target.<elementName>.value`

Comment: can you elaborate 'return the values in an object using a callback function to the parent component' ?

Comment: Add ```formSubmitCb: (formObj: <Add your type here>) => void; ``` to your prop. Then you can do ```props.formSubmitCb(<BuildAndPassFormValuesHere>)```